# Moving a zend framework project to a sub folder

Tags: zend-framework

What do I need to change to get my zend framework site to run in a sub folder. e.g.

www.mydomain.com to www.mynewdomain.com/myfolder/

not having a lot of luck as all I get when i run my rest api is a blank screen and no xml?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can start with `Zend_Controller_Front::setBaseUrl()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application.ini you should have a entry called baseurl which you need to set. Also verify that your .htaccess points to the right folder.

Otherwise the  `Zend_Controller_Front::setBaseUrl()` would go in your bootstrap.php.

Comment: I have neither in either, where about shall I put it?

Comment: I tried the following but it didn't do anything...

protected function _initSetupBaseUrl() {
  $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
  $controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $controller->setBaseUrl('/api'); 
 }

Comment: @StephenBrown edit your question and add your bootstrap code, application.ini and folder structure. Very hard to guess here.